# How to show image from an external database (kotlin)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-external-storage

Hello guys I want to make app with an External Database, I made my Database with SQLite browser, Put my image to drawable, I need to show image and text but it just shows text I mean it works
(Image does not show also this is not any error log about it )
For more guidance I have some code in Adapter
also I put gitlab link
any help would be appreciate. Thank you

```
    class model {
        var id:Int?=null
        var name:String?=null
        var image:String?=null
    }
```

```
    object info_db {
    
        val dbName="country"
        val dbversion=2
        val dbId="id"
        val dbcname="name"
        val dbimage="image"
        val packageData="data/data/com.alialim.countrylist_sample/databases/"
        val source ="country.sqlite"
    
    }
```

```
    class Database(val context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context,info_db.dbName,null,info_db.dbversion)  {
        override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        }
    
        override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    
        }
    
        init {
            initDatabase()
        }
        private fun initDatabase() {
    
            var file = File(info_db.packageData)
    
            if (file.exists()) {
    
            } else {
                file.mkdirs()
            }
    
            file = context.getDatabasePath(info_db.dbName)
            if (file.exists()) {
    
            } else {
                copyDataBase()
            }
    
        }
    
        private fun copyDataBase() {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open(source)
            val outFile = packageData + dbName
            val uotPutStream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var lenght = 0
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also({ lenght = it }) > 0)
                uotPutStream.write(buffer, 0, lenght)
            uotPutStream.flush()
            uotPutStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("Range")
        fun getAll(): ArrayList<model> {
            val db = readableDatabase
            val query = "SELECT * FROM countrylist"
            var list: ArrayList<model> = ArrayList()
            val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val lmodel = model()
                    lmodel.id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(info_db.dbId))
                    lmodel.name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(info_db.dbcname))
    
                    lmodel.image=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(info_db.dbimage))
                    list.add(lmodel)
                    Log.d(
                        "massage",
                        "log Database name ==>${lmodel.name} and category ==> ${lmodel.image}  "
                    )
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
            return list
        }
    }
```

```
    object Base: Application() {
        var database: Database?=null
        var activity: Activity?=null
    
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
        }
    }
```

```
    class AdapterCountry(val context: Context, val countrylists:ArrayList<model>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCountry.HolderCountry>() {
    
        class HolderCountry(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
            val imagerecy=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.recycler_main_image)
            val txtfname=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recycler_main_text)
    
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HolderCountry {
            val layout= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false)
            return HolderCountry(layout)
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HolderCountry, position: Int) {
            val countrylist=countrylists.get(position)
            holder.txtfname.text=countrylist.name
            //code that should display the images but dosent work
            val img=countrylist.image
            val Image: Int = Base.activity!!.getResources()
                .getIdentifier(img, "drawable", Base.activity!!.getPackageName())
            holder.imagerecy.setImageResource(Image)
            //////////////
        }
        override fun getItemCount()=countrylists.size
    }
```

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        var btnclick: Button?=null
        var recycler: RecyclerView?=null
        var adaptecounry: AdapterCountry?=null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            btnclick=findViewById(R.id.showcountrye)
            recycler=findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_recy_image)
            Base.activity=this
            Base.database= Database(this)
            btnclick!!.setOnClickListener {
                recycler!!.setHasTransientState(true)
                recycler!!.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(Base.activity)
                val list= Base.database!!.getAll()
                adaptecounry = AdapterCountry(Base.activity!!,list)
                recycler!!.adapter=adaptecounry
    
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

[SQLitebrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoOpO.png)
[drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA9xv.png)

please visit : https://gitlab.com/salin1/country_list/-/tree/master

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Hello everybody I could fix my problem because  I was Short of time anyway
I writ my correct code here maybe one day somebody like me needed it, My cod is correct but you need to put this code in your RecyclerView Adapter

```
   

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HolderCountry, position: Int) {

        val countrylist=countrylists.get(position)
        Log.i("imaaagee","${countrylist.image}")
        holder.txtfname.text=countrylist.name
        val img=countrylist.name
        img!!.trim()
        val identifier=context.resources.getIdentifier(img,"drawable",
        context!!.getPackageName())
        holder.imagerecy.setImageResource(identifier)

    }
```

also I put link and image if you look at my database image you see in image column I write image name with format (.png) but its mistake because  getIdentifier does not need image format the all thing you should do is put your image to drawable and recover with your adapter code
for more understanding I put my gitlab link you can download and see code
if you have any question just ask I will respond
Thank you